# What is the equivalent of a UITableView for WinForms

Tags: c#, ios, .net, winforms

Is there any component that mimics or provides functionality similar to the iOSs UITableView? I want a nice list, with smooth animations on ordering, delete , custom items in list?

Is there any 'ready-made' open source or commercial component that gives me an equivalent for ordinary WinForms (no XAML/WPF)?

Comment: windorms doesn't support animations, and does not have anything that looks good, and does not allow you to customize anything easily. It is a really old technology no one cares about, and is only good for producing Windows 3.1-like stuff. That's why WPF has created to replace it. If you care about look and feel and user experience, instead of spending lot of $$$ to buy third party components for a dead technology I suggest you use current technologies such as WPF. You can even integrate WPF content in an existing winforms application by using an `ElementHost`.

Comment: @HighCore Thank you,i will convert my projeck to WPF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic WinForms ListBox has completely no animations or any kind of "nice looking appearance". You can check that pack http://www.telerik.com/products/winforms.aspx or devart analogue.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're going to WPF (congratulations for that), you may want to have a look at the `ReorderListBox` control in the [WPF Bag of Tricks](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/bot).

It supports reordering by dragging items and the like. You can find the full source code and many interesting examples in the Bag.